# Using the right dpi on vector icons

Tags: android, svg, icons, android-vectordrawable

I'm new on android studio and planning to design an app for tablets and phones. Therefore my app will be mostly used on normal and large screens.

- Which dpi is best for my vector icons ?
- Should I make different dpi versions of the same icon for multiple screen support ?
- Why only making the icons `wrap_content` doesnt support multiple screen sizes. I thought vector images doesnt get blurred when they are distorted.

Answer (score 2):

The "dpi" for vector icons is meaningless.  Vector icons are DPI independent. That's the whole point of them.  It doesn't matter what size you design them at. It only makes a difference what size you draw (render) them at at run time.  The bigger the size it is displayed at, the more pixels have to be calculated and drawn.

That's what the second paragraph in @muhammad-younas answer (which is from [this Colt McAnlis blog](https://medium.com/@duhroach/how-vectordrawable-works-fed96e110e35)) is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I use `InkScape` for editing and save my `SVG` files (vector images). In theory, it scales well for any size. In theory...

In *Android Studio* I use `New`, `Vector Asset`, and I select the `SVG` file and it generates a `XML` file, below `drawables` folder, under `res` folder. But sometimes, without any explanation, the image was blurred in my phone (Not blurred in the *Android Studio* preview). It's crazy.

I've tried everything, and just one action has solved my problem:

I've decided to change `XML` file directly in *Android Studio*. I read something about `width` and `height` specs (image size) vs `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` (image real size in the cell phone)

So I've decided scaled up the first `width` and `height` pair

For instance, one blurred image has:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="6.415605dp"
    android:height="5.33568dp"
    android:viewportWidth="6.415605"
    android:viewportHeight="5.33568">
 ....
</vector>
```

I've set in my head the `width = 25dp`, so I've made `25 / 6.415605 = 3.89675`. So I've multiplied both numbers in the first pair by  `3.89675`. So I've got new values for `width` and `height`.

It's just a random guess. The important is to make `width` and `height` much bigger than `viewport width` and `viewport height`, preserving the proportions.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="20.7915dp"
    android:viewportWidth="6.415605"
    android:viewportHeight="5.33568">
 ....
</vector>
```

It works like a charm ...